# count number of sublist that contain 3 common elements in Python 3

Tags: python, list, count, nested-lists, sublist

I am using Python 3.4 and Wing Personal in Windows 7.
I have a list of a list of ints and a second list that contains 3 ints.  I would like to identify how many times all 3 elements of list [b] appear in list [a].

```
a=[[1, 6, 11,12, 14, 15], [4, 11, 23, 32, 45, 48], 
  [3, 7, 11, 14, 15, 17], [1, 8, 14, 24, 45, 53], 
  [2, 5, 9, 24, 34, 40], [10, 11,13, 14, 15, 22, 36]]

b=[11,14,15]
count =0
anotherList = []
for sublist in a:
    for element in b:              
        if element in sublist:
            anotherList.append(element)
            count+=1
    print (anotherList)
    print (count/3)
```

Here the count should be 3, not 3.6 and while floor division would cure this it does not help if list [a] contains 20 sublist and a single 14 occurred in 6 of the sublist.

The problem is this counts the total number of times any of the elements in list [b] occur in list [a], rather than the pattern of all 3 elements. I divided by 3 thinking that would make count correct till I realized if only a 14 occurred in a list that was also counted so the count would be off.

Note that index is different in each list and sometimes another element occurs in between the elements I want to identify.  ie, the elements are not always together as 11,14,15. sometimes there is another element in between.

I considered trying to delete all numbers except 11,14,15 then delete all list less than 3 elements long but somehow that does not seem to be the way to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not simply use `set`? Convert `b` to set a see if it is a subset of the items in the list using the [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) method:

```
b = {11,14,15}  #notice the {} braces or use `set([11,14,15])`
print sum(b.issubset(x) for x in a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all` with `sum`:

```
print(sum(all(ele in sub for ele in b ) for sub in  a))
```

Comment: list b has to be dict notation to make this work, right?